Filtrar array de objetos en javascript de varios niveles
Estoy intentado filtrar el siguiente array de objetos por el dato de "integrantes.rol.nombre", para obtener los integrantes por el nombre del rol:
const array = [{
        "id":461073,
        "created":"2024-04-02T14:07:47.913Z", 
        "activo":true, 
        "integrantes":[
            {
                "id":520008, 
                "nombres":"Anthony Ronald",
                "apellidoPaterno":"Jimenez",
                "apellidoMaterno":"Padilla",
                "carnetIdentidad":"135398776", 
                "rol":{
                    "id":1, 
                    "nombre":"Representante" 
                }
            },
            {
                "id":537967, 
                "nombres":"CRISTHOFER",
                "apellidoPaterno":"DAVALOS",
                "apellidoMaterno":"GUZMAN",
                "carnetIdentidad":"6478978964", 
                "rol":{
                    "id":2, 
                    "nombre":"Afiliado" 
                }
            },
            {
                "id":537968, 
                "nombres":"MIREYA",
                "apellidoPaterno":"rojas",
                "apellidoMaterno":"dava",
                "carnetIdentidad":"65464564", 
                "rol":{
                    "id":2, 
                    "nombre":"Afiliado" 
                }
            }
        ]
    }];

Intente usar la función "filter" para obtener el integrante con el rol "Representante" pero me salen muchos errores:
const result = Object.values(array.integrantes).filter(rol:roles=>roles.nombre==="Representante");

Por favor si alguien me podría dar alguna guía para lograrlo.

Hola Cdg, tenes varios errores de conceptos. 1.- La variable array es un objeto. 2.- array.integrantes es un arreglo, podes usar .filter directamente sobre esta propiedad sin necesidad de hacer nada. 3.- Dentro de integrantes tenes objetos, al aplicar filter la función a recorrer uno a uno los objetos y la sintaxis de parámetros no es correcta. 4.- Los objetos serían un integrante (no un rol) del cual necesitas evaluar su .rol.nombre. Espero que esto te sea de ayuda para que puedas solucionarlo por tu cuenta.

El comentario de @Marcos me hizo notar que la relación de "rol" con cada integrante era de 1 a 1, por lo que solo era necesario acceder a nodo "integrante.rol.nombre" para realizar el filtrado.
const result2 =  array.integrantes.filter(
        inte=> inte.rol.nombre==="Representante")
    ;


Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
